# Open ai text-davinci-003 always returning one suggestion?

Tags: node.js, openai-api

I am trying to get array of suggestions (multiple suggestions) for some prompt from nodejs.
Here is what I have so far:

```
const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: complitionModel,
            prompt: `${finalCommand}: ${text}`,
            max_tokens: 256,
            temperature: 0,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0,
            presence_penalty: 0,
            user: user.id
        });
```

But it always return one suggestion (array with single element), no metter what prompt or text i send... Any idea why?

Comment: i couldnt try myself since my api key has reached usage limits. hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the documentation says a parameter [**`n`**](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-n) which is 1 by default

> How many completions to generate for each prompt.
>
> Note: Because this parameter generates many completions, it can
> quickly consume your token quota. Use carefully and ensure that you
> have reasonable settings for `max_tokens` and `stop`.

```js
const completion = await openai.createCompletion({
            model: complitionModel,
            prompt: `${finalCommand}: ${text}`,
            max_tokens: 256,
            temperature: 0,
            top_p: 1,
            frequency_penalty: 0,
            presence_penalty: 0,
            user: user.id,
            n: noOfCompletions //1 by default
        });
```

**Note**
you may get the same results even with a higher `n` with a [`temperature`](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-temperature) of `0`. The docs say

> What sampling temperature to use, between 0 and 2. Higher values like 0.8 will make the output more random, while lower values like 0.2 will make it more focused and deterministic.

Also [this](https://community.openai.com/t/duplicate-results-in-completion-choices/12680) forum post addresses this issue

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But now I always get same suggestions (if n: 3 then 3 x first suggestion)? even when i play with top_p and temperature.. Do I need something additional to configure ?

Comment: could be [temperature](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions/create#completions/create-temperature) it says higher the value more random. also this [post](https://community.openai.com/t/duplicate-results-in-completion-choices/12680)